# Register/Login using only phone number?

Tags: login, user-registration

Does anybody know how WP could be configured to use only a person's phone number as credentials?

The flow would be as such;

User enters number
..Receives a PIN
Enter the PIN
.. Assigns a password to the account.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This question is very broad, can you break it down into smaller pieces and focus on one of those? It's okay if you have a question for each part, currently your question is vast in its scope and extremely unlikely to get an answer

Comment: Thanks Tom. Actually I wouldn't know where to start to break the question down as I'm not a coder. I am just looking to see if the "concept" is sound and do-able at which point I would seek further expert advice. Thanks again for your input.

Comment: It is possible but it is a lot of components to customize: registration form, registration validation, username (to phone number), activation notification (send PIN to phone), PIN validation, and password assignment.

Answer (score -1):

you can change the type of data used for signing in for the username portion, assuming it's data that you have stored about the user (either in the main user table or usermeta). there would still need to be a password, but that in theory could also be mapped to the same data (phone number in your case)

the issue of it being secure is separate, however, because phone numbers are easy enough to get.